Issue when someone else raise pull request to my repository
This workflow gives an error when someone raises a PR. It works fine in the issue section.
name: Greetings
on:
  issues:
    types:
      - opened
  pull_request:
    types:
      - opened

jobs:
  Greetings:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - env:
          GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        run: |
          if [[ "${{ github.event_name }}" == "issues" ]]; then
            gh issue comment ${{ github.event.issue.html_url }} --body "@${{ github.event.issue.user.login }}
            
            Thank you for raising this issue! 
            
            We truly appreciate your contribution to this project and will review the details shortly. ️✨
            We will get back to you soon!
            
            Thank you for your patience! "
          elif [[ "${{ github.event_name }}" == "pull_request" ]]; then
            gh pr comment ${{ github.event.pull_request.html_url }} --body "@${{ github.event.pull_request.user.login }}
            
            Thank you for your Pull Request!
            
            We truly appreciate your contribution! 
            We will review the changes and provide feedback or merge the PR soon. 
            Please stay tuned for updates! 
            
             Thank you for your efforts in improving the project! "
          fi

I have given read and write permissions to the workflow. You can see it in the screenshot below:

I am facing this error:

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/writing-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#permissions

Since the body is one big "if it's an issue, do this, if it's a pull request, do that" this would be simpler as two workflows.

Rather than doing this with the gh tool, consider the Comment Progress action.

@Schwern I tried but not working.

secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN is limited by design, commenting on PR need more permission.
The solution will be to create a “Create a Personal Access Token (PAT)” with the needed permission.
Create the PAT:
Your account settings -> Developer Settings -> Personal access tokens ->
Generate a new token with the repo scope (there's now a beta in GH that let you create this kind specifically very easily, great timing to have your issue).
Add PAT to repo:
Repo -> Settings -> Secrets and variables -> Actions -> add new secret and name it something (Lets assume PAT_TOKEN for convenience) and paste the PAT you created.
Update the action to use the new PAT_TOKEN.
Change the on section to:
on:
  pull_request_target:
    types: opened

  issues:
    types: opened

The reason is that when a user open a PR, it runs on his branch, and his branch doesn't have access to secrets.
pull_request_target always run from main branch.
A very important security point — never add checkout step to a workflow running on pull_request_target, it can be abuse easily.

Two points -
To get better help, fully open the drop-down.
If the headline of the section erroring is “XYZ” that doesn't mean the error is in “XYZ” but that it is in the step of “XYZ”, so the issue is not in the comparison explicitly (which I really believe it's not).

@OmManiya let me know if it works

I created PAT and given all the permissions and modified above code to this : https://github.com/maniyaom/sample-repo/blob/main/.github/workflows/greetings.yml

its seems that you call github.token, instead of secrets.pat_token

I have tried both but both are not working

Editing my answer

Edited. its about the on section. as for myself i think its ok to have the same workflows for both issue and pr, its all greetings.

sure! good luck
